# How to store images in Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain?

Tags: image, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am new in Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain.

Is this possible to store images in Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain?

If yes, then how can I do that? I believe we can store images by converting them to **base64** string.

What is the **maximum size** of the image we can store in the Hyperledger Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

If the chaincode is written in java then we use ChaicodeStub.putState(String key, byte[] value) method to save the data into blockchain.

A Java byte array can hold up to 2^31-1 values, if there is contiguous memory available.

P.S: An alternative approach could be to store the hash of the image in blockchain.

[Documentation](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/blob/release-1.4/fabric-chaincode-shim/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/shim/ChaincodeStub.java#L144)

Comment: If we store the hash key of the image it doesn't mean storing the image. Hash key never converts into the image as i knew it.